# How to get multiple ObjectStores using one transaction in an indexed database

Tags: javascript

I have multiple ObjectStores inside indexeddb, and I need to get them all at once, but I can't.

I tried this code below but it is not working.

```
db.transaction(['category','time'],'readonly').objectStore(['category','time']).getAll().addEventListener('success', async function(e){
        console.log(e.target.result)
});
```

Comment: Please specify what is not working for you. For example, if there is an error message, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To get multiple ObjectStores in one transaction from an IndexedDB database, you need to create separate object stores for each of them and then access them separately within the transaction.

```
const request = indexedDB.open('myDatabase', 1);
// Create object stores
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
const db = event.target.result;
const categoryStore = db.createObjectStore('category', { keyPath: 'id' });
const timeStore = db.createObjectStore('time', { keyPath: 'id' });
};
// Access object stores within transaction
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
const db = event.target.result;
const tx = db.transaction(['category', 'time'], 'readonly');
const categoryStore = tx.objectStore('category');
const timeStore = tx.objectStore('time');
const categoryData = await categoryStore.getAll();
const timeData = await timeStore.getAll();
console.log(categoryData, timeData);
};
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to select a specific key?